# Why do I get Error 401 trying to patch Auth0 app_metadata with the Management API?

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, axios, auth0

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to solve issuing a patch request after getting an access token. This same access token works for get requests to https://${appDomain}/api/v2/users/${userid}. But it fails with "Request failed with status code 401" when trying to use it to patch app_metadata.

Using NodeJS and Axios.

```js
         axios
          .post(`https://${appDomain}/oauth/token`, {
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
            client_id: clientId,
            client_secret: clientSecret,
            audience: `https://${appDomain}/api/v2/`,
          })
          .then(({ data: { access_token, token_type } }) => {
            const jwt = jwtDecode(access_token)

            axios
              .patch(`https://${appDomain}/api/v2/users/${userid}`, {
                data: {
                  app_metadata: { stripeCustomerId: customer.id },
                },
                headers: {
                  Authorization: `${token_type} ${access_token}`,
                },
              })
              .then(({ data }) => {
                console.warn('patch response', data)
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.error('patch error', err) // <--- ERROR 401 happens here
                res.send(err)
              })
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error('token error', err)
            res.send(err)
          })
```

Answer (score 1):

After shadow boxing documentation I discovered a syntax error in my axios.patch call. Format should have been the following, which fixed my problems. I was passing data:{...} when it should have been like this:

```
              axios.patch(
                `https://${appDomain}/api/v2/users/${userid}`,
                {
                  app_metadata: { stripeCustomerId: customer.id },
                },
                {
                  headers: {
                    Authorization: `${token_type} ${access_token}`,
                  },
                }
              )
```